# At page Load div is not hiding text

Tags: html, css

At page Load `div` should hide `Text` but it is not hiding

```
<div id="div1" style="width: 1px; height: 1px;">
    Hello.................................<br />
    Hello.................................<br />
    Hello.................................<br />
    .......
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just do style="display:none;" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to the `div`:

```
<div id="div1" style="width: 1px; height: 1px;overflow:auto;">
    Hello.................................<br />
    Hello.................................<br />
    Hello.................................<br />
    .......
</div>
```

The overflow declaration tells the browser what to do with content that doesn't fit in a box.
More information here: [*http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html*](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html)

Comment: Thanks for very good answer and providing information about `overflow`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `overflow:hidden` to your style:
`<div id="div1" style="width:1px; height:1px; overflow:hidden">`